# Could an *implicitly* defined graph be a member of a *strongly-explicit* family of expanders?

Tags: quantum-computing, terminology, expanders, sparse-matrix

There seems to be a slight difference in terminology among a couple of different traditions within theoretical computer science.

- To have a quantum computer [simulate the Hamiltonian evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_simulation) of $\exp(-iAt)$ of some $2^n\times 2^n$ hermitian matrix $A$ giving the adjacency matrix of a sparse undirected graph on $2^n$ vertices, it suffices that we are also provided oracle access to query different vertices to have adjacent vertices returned in order, so that we can partition the adjacency matrix $A$ with edge-colors and subsequently Trotterize the partition;
- In the theory of expanders, as explained by O'Donnell [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/toolkit13/lecture12.pdf) it's a rather trivial result that most (Erdős–Rényi) sparse random graphs have good expansion properties; what applications generally require is an *explicit* family of graphs.  But, when we are also provided oracular access to adjacent vertices, this has been referred to as a ***strongly explicit*** family of expanders; while
- Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_graph) an ***implicit*** graph representation as is a graph whose vertices or edges are not represented as explicit objects in a computer's memory, but rather are determined algorithmically.

It's these last two terms that I'm wondering about - is it correct to say that an **implicitly defined** graph could be a member of a **strongly explicit** family of expanders (and, if so, could it be amenable to Hamiltonian simulation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! But I can see why it is confusing.

A *strongly explicit* graph family $\{G_n = (V_n,E_n)\}$ (parameterized e.g. by number of vertices $n$) is described by an efficient ($\mathrm{polylog}(n)$ time) algorithm that takes as input a vertex $v \in V_n$ and an index $\ell$, and returns the $\ell$-th neighbor of $v$ (according to some order). This is the usual model considered for quantum Hamiltonian simulation with the graph's adjacency matrix $A_n$.

Regarding the confusion with wikipedia's definition of "implicitly defined": in CS/combinatorics, a graph family is called *explicit* if we can provide an algorithm to explicitly generate the graph (i.e., write it down in memory) in time $\mathrm{poly}(n)$. This is weaker than being *strongly* explicit. So the algorithm is an *implicit* description of the graph, and its description size could be much smaller than the memory size required to write down the full adjacency matrix/list explicitly (e.g., $\mathrm{polylog}(n)$ versus $\mathrm{poly}(n)$).